# Can I mute the sound when switching users in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, fast-user-switching

We have a win 7 computer that is used by several family members and we use fast user switching to change accounts without logging each other out (It's set up to go to the select user screen after resuming from screensaver). However, often someone will accidentaly leave windows media player or a website playing sound. This is very irritating since it means you have to switch between all the accounts to find out who is playing music and attempt to stop it.

Is there a way to set up windows 7 to mute or pause audio playback when switching to another user?

Comment: yes, same question, although mine was asked first ;)

Comment: Ha, I guess I should look at dates before being a smarty pants.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a VBS script to mute the sound, then create a task scheduler, then setting the trigger to “on workstation lock”.

There should be tutorials online detailing this if you need help.

Comment: Would the VBS script be able to mute applications (as opposed to muting all sound, which wouldn't help, since this seems to be shared between users)?