# Mute sound from other users in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

I recently moved from Ubuntu to Windows 7 on my home PC. It has generally been a quite pleasant experience, but of course some things are not perfect. Among them is this issue:

When for exampe my son is playing a game in his browser and *I use fast user switching to get to my account, his sound is still playing*. This is of course very annoying if I want to play some sound of my own.

My options seem to be:

- Mute all sound (for all users)
- Kill his (and all other users') applications that output sound

I would like *this* behaviour:

- When I log in, all sound from other users is automatically muted

*Is this possible?* It sounds like the obvious behaviour, but some googling leads me to believe this is how Windows behaves.

Comment: I am shocked that this isn't the default behavior.  Lazy design!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I mute the sound when switching users in Win 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/201053/can-i-mute-the-sound-when-switching-users-in-win-7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use MonitorES (http://code.google.com/p/monitores/) here at work to mute the sound whenever I lock my system. I assume it would work similarly over fast user switching but I've not tested it. It's worth a shot. It's a standalone executable that sits in the taskbar and it's free.

I know there's an option to stop media players from playing and also to mute but if it's a game it may not mute it. In Windows 7 I believe there are application based sound preferences so you could mute the browser's sound but then it would also be muted for you. If you're the one doing the switching, you could always mute his game before the switch. (Not ideal I know). But that's Microsoft's official position on it: "To resolve this behavior, either upgrade the programs, if applicable, or stop the sound-emitting program before switching users." from support.microsoft.com/kb/301681

Comment: I wonder if it just mutes the sound? Because if I log into my son's account and mute sound there, my sound is muted as well.

Comment: I know there's an option to stop media players from playing and also to mute but if it's a game it may not mute it. In Windows 7 I believe there are application based sound preferences so you could mute the browser's sound but then it would also be muted for you. If you're the one doing the switching, you could always mute his game before the switch. (Not ideal I know). But that's Microsoft's official position on it: "To resolve this behavior, either upgrade the programs, if applicable, or stop the sound-emitting program before switching users." from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301681

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer and I will accept that one! Muting the offending applications is an acceptable solution for me. I will research the APIs though to see if I can write a small program that does this.

Comment: @myself: Seems like IAudioSessionEnumerator enumerates sessions which hopefully can be used with GetSimpleAudioVolume to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same frustration and decided to scratch this particular itch. The result is Sound Killer - http://jugglingcats.github.io/soundkiller. Enjoy.