# Windows-7 audio: controlling volume of applications on different user session

Tags: windows-7, audio, session, multiple-users, volume-mixer

My usecase is as this.

The PC is shared and there are two users logged in at the same time.
The first user puts internet radio on speaker, has got browser running with some rogue tab opened that plays a sound from time to time.

The second user switches to his user session leaving the other running with the audio.
All is well until Skype call comes in, or the user decides to play a youtube clip.
There seem to be no way to control the audio of the applications on the other session (or even entire session) from the built-in mixer.

The harsh method is to kill the winamp/browser on the other session.

Perhaps there is a simple way to do that.

Note: I tried running volume.exe with admin rights - does not help.

Comment: I do not think you have another alternative except killing the process of the application used by the other user account. In your case Winamp or the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, there is no way normally to modify the sound volumes and applications of another user's session. A similar issue to this one was explored in [Mute sound from other users in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/233242/mute-sound-from-other-users-in-windows-7).

**A work around was developed** by one of the users in the linked question, which is **available at** http://jugglingcats.github.io/soundkiller/, courtesy of [jugglingcats](https://superuser.com/users/219846/jugglingcats). This application will automatically mute all applications when switching users, and un-mute them when switching back.

This fix however, will not suspend applications in any way, continuing to use CPU time and bandwidth in the background. For this, the only solution is that users exercise some courtesy and close applications that will impact on other users before switching sessions, or log off completely.

This is also the stance which Microsoft takes, expecting that you disable all sound emitting applications manually before switching user accounts. (Courtesy of [peroty](https://superuser.com/users/18654/peroty) from the aforementioned question. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301681)

Under Windows 8, the above workaround is not required as this functionality is built into the OS.

As an Administrator, it may be possible to force switching to another user's account to (if the appropriate permissions are granted) or to log another user out, thus closing all applications they had running.

It is also possible as an Administrator to kill the processes of the application, as mentioned in the comments to your question by [Corporate Geek](https://superuser.com/users/4381/corporate-geek).